# How to create and update a global variable in Jinja?

Tags: variables, namespaces, set, jinja2, global

I'd like to create a global (boolean) variable with Jinja and update it in an if-statement. I try to do this as follows:

```
{% set variable = true %} 
{% if True %}  
    {% set variable = false %} 
{% endif %} 
{{ variable }}
```

I'd like the print to be **False, but now it is True**.

Should I create a variable to a namespace or is there simpler way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That code as is working and is printing `False`

Comment: @JBone, for me the variable in the if-statement changes locally. When start printing {{ variable }} in the end it prints again True.